# Where can I learn about handling audio IO and codecs in python3?

Tags: python, audio, io, python-3.x, codec

I'm planning on writing a simple, plugin-friendly audio player in Python (à la foobar2000), but don't even know where to begin.  I've never handled any IO other than plain text.  Could somebody recommend some resources on handling audio and audio codecs in Python?  If there's any well-commented source code from existing python audio players, that'd be extremely helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A music player needs a GUI, right?
Why not go with [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/) - a Python binding for the Qt cross-platform UI framework and it's awesome multimedia framework [Phonon](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside-1.0.8/PySide/phonon/index.html)?

It's all cross-platform and works with Python 3.

However, I'm not really sure where to get started with Phonon... it's probably just the documentation.
And [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/) is a good tutorial for the GUI part of PySide.

Comment: I started trying to make it using Tkinter, although I'm still just trying to figure out the basics of Tkinter at this point.  Since school started, I haven't had much time to get anything done yet, or even familiarize myself with Tkinter, so if you think PySide is a better choice than Tkinter, given a few good reasons to switch, I wouldn't mind switching at all.

Comment: The first time I read your post, I missed the bit about Phonon being a multimedia framework.  I'm working on getting PySide installed right now.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

What might be helpful (especially if you are on Linux) is the source of '[Minirok](http://tuxarena.blogspot.com/2009/06/minirok-20-minimalist-audio-player-for.html)'. Not really sure about the state of its internals (comments etc).

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at Minirok.  I use Linux for everything but gaming, so that's my target platform, but if it's not too difficult, I'd like to make this work cross-platform on Linux/Windows/OS X.  How portable are the audio IO and codec handlers in python?

Answer (score 1):

The [PythonInMusic](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) section of the python wiki has a list of python audio players.

Comment: None of those actually work with Python3.  As far as I can tell, there's currently no way to play anything other than wav, iff, aiff, aifc, and au.  It's pretty surprising that Python3 has been out for this long, yet none of the audio libraries have been ported.